# how to create communication with dynamic text box

Tags: zk

How to communicate between dynamic textbox that without id .

In normal case  we can have some of the event name  `onchange` and `etc` . but in dynamic component. We don't have that key (id) to link it.  Like `onchange$id` then do something "".

so in dynamic component case , how to get value from dynamic component? Please provide idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your question isn't very precise (about how you create those components dynamicall - java or zul templates) here the 2 basic methods:

**from java code**:

after creating a new component just add an event listener programmatically, no need for any convention based method names.

```
//create dynamically anywhere
Textbox someInput = new Textbox();
someInput.setParent(someParent);
someInput.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGE, this::onChangeSomeInput);
//someInput.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGE, (InputEvent event) -> {...});
...

public void onChangeSomeInput(InputEvent event) {
   Textbox someInput = event.getTarget();
   someInput.getValue();
}
```

**from zul code**:

in this case [event forwarding](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Forwarding) is the tool of choice, it lets you delegate the event to a parent component with an id

```
<grid id="mygrid">
  <template name="model">
    <row>
      <textbox forward="onChange=mygrid.onChangeSomeInput(${each})"/>
    </row>
  </template>
</grid>
```

then you can implement a composer method like this

```
public void onChangeSomeInput$mygrid(ForwardEvent forwardEvent) {
    InputEvent event = (InputEvent)forwardEvent.getOrigin();
    Object each = forwardEvent.getData();
}
```

(I wrote this code our of my head so please excuse typos/errors, I'll be happy to provide running examples in case you specify your question)